# Could you help me understand this PHP code with a PDO query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Good colleagues, I am learning PHP a little more thoroughly since I am a bit newbie, I already did database queries with MySQLi and I want to learn the PDO alternative since I can connect to other databases other than MySQL.
So I decided to see different examples and I found one that I did not understand well so I decided to see line by line.

```
<?php
    function doSomething($id){
        
        $pdo= conecta(); 
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $motivo= "probar"; 
        $res=0;
        $e="";

        try{
            $pdo->beginTransaction();

            $sql= "INSERT INTO registro (nombre_c, desc_c, motivo_c) (SELECT nombre_a, desc_a, :motivo FROM autos WHERE id=:id)";
            $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt->bindParam(':motivo', $motivo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $res1 = $stmt->execute();
            
            $sql="DELETE FROM autos WHERE id=:id";
            $stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $res2 = $stmt->execute();

            $pdo->commit();
            $res=$res1&&$res2;
        }catch(PDOException $e){
            $pdo->rollBack();
        }

        unset($stmt);
        unset($pdo);
        return array($res?"actualizado":"error", $e);

    }

?>
```

My idea is to understand it line by line so that what I learned is better for me.
And from what I see a Method is created that receives the $ id property and connects to a database and an update is created (of which I do not know if the query is well done because it seems strange to me)
I am having a hard time understanding PDO queries, so I wanted to see what tips or advice you could give me.

**My query is to know and decipher what exactly does the function since it confuses me a lot**

Comment: Are you asking about something specific to PDO or the `INSERT... SELECT` query? For the latter, see https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp

Comment: `$id` is a param that is being bound. What is your question? If you did `mysqli` this shouldn't be that much harder to understand.

Comment: @StackSlave Why advise `mysqli` over `PDO`? That is going the wrong way.

Comment: The question is unclear, you're going to need to clarify. A `query` is just SQL that performs some function, and PDO is a driver that sends the query to the DB. There are other drivers but they are usually limited to a specific database. PDO is more versatile and can work with many DBs.

Comment: @user3783243, I never advised that in my comment. but if you're using MySQL mysqli is way less to type, as it does not require a separate method for each param.

Comment: @StackSlave I strongly disagree with your comment, and summation of your comment. But to the `bindparam` point, that isn't needed at all. The `execute` method can run bindings on its own with PDO.

Comment: My query is to know and decipher what exactly does the function since it confuses me a lot

Comment: Essentially it moves a record from `autos` table to the `registro` table. If you want specifics please clarify which part you are confused by. The manual has explanations for all of these functions.

Comment: @user3783243... or passing an Array to `->execute`. It's more to type for sure... but that's not the question. OP, doesn't seem to have a question, just lacks understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$pdo= conecta();
```

I suppose this is a successfully connected pdo object.

```
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

This means that pdo will throw an exception once it encounters an error. (As an alternative example you can set it to `PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING`, and it will produce a php warning on error)

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
```

By this you tell PDO that you begin communicating with the database, after which you might want to accept the changes by `$pdo->commit();` or decline them by `$pdo->rollBack();`

Thus, each `$pdo->beginTransaction();` must be finished with either `$pdo->commit();` or `$pdo->rollBack();`

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO registro (nombre_c, desc_c, motivo_c) (SELECT nombre_a, desc_a, :motivo FROM autos WHERE id=:id)";
$stmt= $pdo->prepare($sql);
```

At this step the string query is passed to PDO and prepared for execution (it's necessary to prevent injections).

```
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':motivo', $motivo,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Binding params is like telling pdo to consider the indicated flags (beginning with : ) equal to the passed variables. The third parameter is the variable type here, often it can be omitted.

```
$res1 = $stmt->execute();
```

Executing the query itself. So at this step the previously prepared query is executed:

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO registro (nombre_c, desc_c, motivo_c) (SELECT nombre_a, desc_a, :motivo FROM autos WHERE id=:id)";
```

Namely, it selects fields `nombre_a`, `desc_a`, and `probar` from table `autos` and then inserts each selected line into table `registro`. But the changes are not displayed in the database yet. If an error occurs in the next `DELETE` query, this insert operation will be rolled back. This is because you started a transaction, which means you don't send any changes to the database without telling PDO to `commit()`.

But after inserting we haven't committed yet. So if `DELETE` query produces an error, PDO will throw an exception, as it is set to the exception error mode. This exception will be caught by try-catch, and the whole transaction will be rolled back.

Otherwise, if `DELETE` is successful, there will be no exception, so the previously inserted data will be `committed` to the database, and the changes will be displayed.